# How to load Win8 native camera app (metro) from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, camera, microsoft-metro

I'm developing an app from javascript, which needs to press a button and open the native camera app, so far I have this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <LINK href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script>
        function capturePhoto() {
            window.open("microsoftvideo:///","_self");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Bar">
            <button id="cmdCamera" value="Picture" onclick="capturePhoto();">Load Picture...</button>
            <input type="file" />
        </div>

     </body>
</html>
```

---

> window.open("microsoftvideo:///","_self");

is the key, since is a metro app you can call them from a WebBrowser address field, it is like going to any website, I can open any metro app from there for instance

- Music app: microsoftmusic:///
- News app: bingnews:///
- Video app: microsoftvideo:///

but I don't know what's the word for invoking camera app any help I'll appreciate

Comment: is there a chance to know how to launch the app if we look inside C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ ????